# Building APK and getting 4 folders instead of the APK file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Building an APK file from a project inside the Android Studio, normally I get the output folder with .apk file inside it, but in this particular case, instead of the APK file, I'm getting 4 folders:

`generated`

`intermediate`

`outputs`

`temp`

Altogether, they hold the weight of what I'd expect the APK file to be. Is there any way to get the APK out of this project?

Comment: you will find apk from this path: /app/build/outputs/apk.

If the apk is not there then run your project once again.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I can't mark the comment as the solution.

Comment: Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"you will find apk from this path: /app/build/outputs/apk. If the apk is not there then run your project once again." – Ronak Thakkar

Answer (score 0):

Please share your build.gradle file . i think there is mistake with this file thats why its not creating build.gradle file.

According to Build Unsigned APK with Gradle you can simply build your application with gradle. In order to do that:

click on the drop down menu on the toolbar at the top (usually with android icon and name of your application)
select Edit configurations
click plus sign at top left corner or press alt+insert
select Gradle
choose your module as Gradle project
in Tasks: enter assemble
press OK
press play